# How to embed third party types in Go?

Tags: go

In my application, the Decimal package [github.com/shopspring/decimal](https://github.com/shopspring/decimal) is used.

In order to write custom functions on the `decimal.Decimal` type, I have created my own `Decimal` type and embedded `decimal.Decimal`:

```
type Decimal struct {
    decimal.Decimal
}
```

This works great, and I can now access `decimal.Decimal` methods on `Decimal` object:

```
a := Decimal{decimal.NewFromFloat(1.0)}
b := Decimal{a.Neg()}
```

Some of `decimal.Decimal` methods requires an argument of type `decimal.Decimal`, f.ex:

```
c := Decimal{a.Add(b)}
```

The above line cannot compile because of error: `cannot use b (variable of type Decimal) as decimal.Decimal value in argument to a.Add`

I have tried to convert `Decimal` to `decimal.Decimal`:

```
c := Decimal{a.Add((decimal.Decimal)(b))}
```

The above code would not compile due to below error:

```
cannot convert b (variable of type Decimal) to decimal.Decimal
```

**Question:** How to extend/embed a third party type in a way that allows the use of "parent" methods *and* can use the extended type as argument in methods that requires argument of parents type?

Comment: Methods that require the original type should be overwritten in the new type. Simple wrappers that pass the embedded value of one to the embedded value of the other. As a bonus, these wrappers can, and should, return the new type, not the original, so you won't have to litter your code with the ugly `Decimal{m()}`.

Comment: If you don't like that approach though, simply do `Decimal{a.Add(b.Decimal)}`. -> The name of an embedded field is the unqualified name of the embedded type.

Comment: I'm shocked there is no good way to do this in Go! 
Using the first approach (overwrite methods in the new type) is cumbersome and (possibly) problematic if the original package is updated. 
Using the latter approach works but the code is quite ugly (as you say, the code is "littered").

Comment: @mkopriva feel free to provide your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Vingtoft You can use embedding to achieve composition and get pass-through methods for free. Or you can add a named field and be more selective about which methods you want to delegate to the inner type. There's no middle ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A field declared with a type but no explicit field name is called an embedded field. An embedded field must be specified as a type name T or as a pointer to a non-interface type name *T, and T itself may not be a pointer type. **The unqualified type name acts as the field name.**

So a quick and dirty solution would be to simply access the field using the "unqualified type name".

```golang
_ = Decimal{a.Add(b.Decimal)}
```

---

If, however, you're looking for a more seamless experience when using the new type, then your only option is to redeclare the methods that require the original type and use the new type in its place. These redeclared methods need only be simple wrappers that pass the embedded field of one instance to the method of the embedded field of the other instance. For example:

```golang
type Time struct {
    time.Time
}

func (t Time) In(loc *time.Location) Time {
    return Time{t.Time.In(loc)}
}

func (t Time) Equal(u Time) bool {
    return t.Time.Equal(u.Time)
}
```